# VSS 2005 Internet Access e IIS 7 - Não consigo configurar para acesso remoto

Tags: iis, resources

Galera, procurei vários tutoriais e nada funciona.

Segui todos os passos [desse link](http://888rock.blogspot.com.br/2010/02/step-by-step-setup-microsoft-visual.html) e quando chega em:

> Now click  “Server” –> “Configuration” –> check on “Enable SourceSafe
>   Internet for this computer” and “Enable SourceSafe Internet for this
>   database” –> Enter your web server dns name –> “OK”

Da erro, dá essa mensagem:

> Visual SourceSafe internet was not enabled on this computer because
>   Internet Information Services(IIS) is not installed.

Já alterei a ID da minha aplicação para 1 para ver se funciona e nada.
E sim, o IIS está instalado e habilitado, existe até um sistema grande funcionando.

Alguém tem uma sugestão?

Comment: Você deu uma baita sorte de não conseguir instalar o VSS. Agora pode procurar um produto realmente seguro para controle de versão :)

Comment: O Windows não possui ferramenta de controle de versão, a Microsoft tem, é o Visual Source Safe... E o VSS 2005 é compatível com Win 8.1.. então não deu problema nenhum para instalar... o negócio é fazer a comunicação entre VSS e IIS para permitir acesso remoto... Se vocês poderem me ajudar agradeço.